# how to open a file using R

Tags: r, windows, file

how to open a file using R? I am thinking about a function like `file.open(...)`, what it does is like double-click a file to open it. However, I did not find any function doing that. Is it possible to use R to open a file? I am using Windows system.

Answer (score 0):

You can also load data into the R environment with the help of the RStudio IDE. On this [website](https://support.posit.co/hc/en-us/articles/218611977-Importing-Data-with-the-RStudio-IDE), you can see how it's done with files such as .txt, .csv, .xlsx, .sav, etc. It's very useful because you can do it with both code and buttons.